# Resolving values of connected object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an Person object that has attributes like `string name` or `int age` and `Profession profession`. Profession has attributes like `int id` and `string description`.

Now what I want is to extract all the values into a string. The string should look like:

> Name: Mr.X, Age: 24, Profession: {Id: 1, Description: IT Specialist}

But with my code I only get

> Name: Mr.X, Age: 24, Profession: Models.Profession

My code is:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    values += pi.Name + ": " + pi.GetValue(myObject) + ", ";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would say the code as it is, is not wrong. An object without overriden `ToString()` function just returns the object name. So you have two options, implement the `ToString()` method or list the properties recursive.

Comment: @thehennyy imo, this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @thehennyy thx 4 your answer! I made it like Maxime said. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do the job:

```
class Profession
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return string.Format("{{Id: {0}, Description: {1}}}", Id, Description);
        string values = string.Empty;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            values += pi.Name + ": " + pi.GetValue(myObject) + ", ";
        return values.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, values.Length - 2));
    }
}
```

**edit:** If you do not want to override ToString() method, something like this would be better:

```
public class Person : AbstractClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
}

public class Profession : AbstractClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public string GetString()
    {
        string values = string.Empty;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractClass)))
                values += pi.Name + ": {" + (pi.GetValue(this) as AbstractClass).GetString() + "}, ";
            else
                values += pi.Name + ": " + pi.GetValue(this) + ", ";
        }
        return values.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, values.Length - 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Id did the job! Great! :)

Comment: I added an other version, which would be better if you keep adding Properties. However I didn't find an easy way to make it generic. The best way I think about is making an interface, and implementing this interface for all your classes... Tell me if you're interested and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for that edit. Exactly, I want to add more properties. I'll try to make your edit work. But thanks for the offer :)